# Get Actual message body of SendGrid email using Curl

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have tried two URL's for getting the exact message body sent from the sendgrid to email

> With this I got below screen
>
> ```
> $url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages/{$messageId}";
> ```
>
> [image]

> With this no responce
>
> ```
> $url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send/{$messageId}";
> ```

#### Tried below Code

```php
$url = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages/{$messageId}";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$message = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($message);
```

Is it possible to get the actual body sent by the mail. I need to check this because I am sending some meta tags in mail and that not showing in the email body after submitted. So thinking that may be SendGrid sending it and blocked by while mail received.

Comment: Poking around in their [API documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/authentication), I can't see anything. you might want to try contacting their support to see if they offer that function.

Comment: Yes I thought same @aynber. Contacting them will get quick resolution

Comment: @aynber is correct. Here's the [URL specifically for the API to get a message by ID](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-messages-by-message-id).
It does not list the email content as part of the response, so there's no way to get it.
aynber, could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend starting off by looking in the [Blocks](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/blocks) and [Invalid](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/invalid_emails) sections of the SendGrid dashboard and doing some initial debugging to find out if SendGrid sent your emails or not, and why.

Secondly, I recommend using [the official SendGrid PHP API library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) instead of hand-crafting a request using curl. Take a look at [the use case examples](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md) as they show a variety of ways of using the library, from the most basic to [a kitchen sink example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#kitchen-sink).

Now, to your question, most directly, you mentioned "*meta tags*" in your original question. Were referring to [personalisations](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations)?

```
<?php

use SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent;
use SendGrid\Mail\Personalization;
use SendGrid\Mail\PlainTextContent;
use SendGrid\Mail\Subject;
use SendGrid\Mail\To;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("sender@example.org", "Sender");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo(
    "receiver@example.org",
    "Reciever",
    [
        '-name-' => 'Example User 1'
    ]
);
$email->addContent(
    new PlainTextContent("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP. -name-")
);
$email->addContent(
    new HtmlContent("<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP. -name-</strong>")
);

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(<<YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY>>']);
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

If so, try the code above. It will replace `-name-` in both the plain text and HTML email bodies with `Example User 1`.

I hope that I understood, correctly, what you were asking, and that this helped out.

Comment: Yes that's the great to get the exact solution for my query. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify I am sending <meta property="some_key" content="test data" /> like these fields I am attaching to start of email body. So SendGrid will send these meta tags? Tried to gmail but not showing in gmails body.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good question. I'll check on meta tags specifically. Gmail may also filter out meta tags too. Well worth checking.

Comment: Here's some documentation showing examples of adding metatags in HTML content: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/substitution-and-section-tags.

Comment: From some searching, I've not found anything to indicate that Gmail strips meta tags. I'm going to do a bit of an experiment to find out.

Comment: After some experimenting, Gmail didn't strip any of the meta tags that I added to the email.

Comment: Thanks again for a clear gudience. I'll check with my sendgrid account whether it's receiving or not. And update you soon.

Comment: Please see my screens [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQqDK.png) & [Mail Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvBko.png).
I did not received meta tags I am using WordPress with sendgrid. Is there any settings do I have to enable in sendgrid or in Gmail is blocking this?

Comment: At a guess, they might have been stripped as metatags should be in the header. Did you look in the header section of the email content? Just guessing without having more to look at.

Comment: I have checked in the header in body still not getting the meta tags also [see this SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC70W.png). Not showing the given content in the mail body of message.

Comment: Hmmm, then I'm not sure, but I'll ask the folks at SendGrid for more info.

Comment: Yes that would be great. Thanks again 